# Cast error with LINQ to XML

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I am attempting to parse an XML feed from a web service with LINQ To XML (My first attempt at it so bear with me). I ave the following function which is supposed to create me an IEnumerable(Of RoomRate) from the XML

```
Public Function ParseRates() As IEnumerable(Of RoomRate)
    Try
        Return From el As XElement In _xDoc...<RoomRate>
                    Select New RoomRate With { _
                       .GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = el.@GuaranteeSurchargeRequired, _
                       .IATACharacteristicIdentification = el.@IATACharacteristicIdentification, _
                       .IATAProductIdentification = el.@IATAProductIdentification, _
                       .RPH = el.@RPH, _
                       .CancellationPolicy = el...<AdditionalInfo>...<CancellationPolicy>.@Numeric, _
                       .Commission = el...<AdditionalInfo>...<Commission>.@NonCommission, _
                       .Rate = el...<Rates>...<Rate>.@Amount, _
                       .CurrencyCode = el...<Rates>...<Rate>.@CurrencyCode, _
                       .TotalPrice = el...<Rates>...<Rate>...<HotelTotalPricing>.@Amount, _
                       .Surcharge = el...<Rates>...<Rate>...<TotalSurchjarges>.@Amount}
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorMessage = ex.Message
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

And I'm testing it like so

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim parse As New ParseSabre(Server.MapPath("~/XML/SabreSample.xml"))
    Dim rates As IEnumerable(Of RoomRate)()

    rates = parse.ParseRates()

    'If rates = Nothing Then

    'End If
    For Each rate As RoomRate In rates
        Response.Write(rate.GuaranteeSurchargeRequired)
        Response.Write(rate.IATACharacteristicIdentification)
        Response.Write(rate.IATAProductIdentification)
        Response.Write(rate.RPH)
        Response.Write(rate.CancellationPolicy)
        Response.Write(rate.Commission)
        Response.Write(rate.Rate)
        Response.Write(rate.CurrencyCode)
        Response.Write(rate.TotalPrice)
        Response.Write(rate.Surcharge)
        Response.Write(vbNewLine)
    Next
End Sub
```

But on this line

**rates = parse.ParseRates()**

I'm getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,Lodgx.Classes.Models.RoomRate]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Lodgx.Classes.Models.RoomRate][]'.

Can someone help me figure out whjere I'm going wrong here?

**EDIT**

I've changed my code to this, is this better? (Also, still getting same error with this code)

```
_rates = _xDoc.Descendants("RoomRate").Select(Function(n) New RoomRate With { _
                .GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = n.Attribute("GuarateeSurchargeRequired").Value, _
                .IATACharacteristicIdentification = n.Attribute("IATACharacteristicIdentification").Value, _
                .IATAProductIdentification = n.Attribute("IATAProductIdentification").Value,
                .RPH = n.Attribute("RPH").Value})
```

Comment: Exactly what I wrote in my comment to your previous question. These kind of issues can be easily avoided if using plain old school code (no LINQ). Please rewrite using that, spot the problem (which is now meaningful) - solved.

Comment: Note that I am not being notified about your changes unless you post a comment and reference me via `@` symbol. Regarding your edit, `.Select` is also LINQ, please rewrite to old school lines of code, i.e. one assignment per line. Your VS will then blow up on the line in question, with a meaningful error. `Dim rr As New RoomRate` : `rr.GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = n.Attribute("GuarateeSurchargeRequired").Value` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, your declaring your variable as an array of `IEnumerable(Of RoomRate)`

```
Dim rates As IEnumerable(Of RoomRate)()
```

(*important part is `()` after type name - that's how you initialize array in VB.NET*) and trying to assign only one `IEnumerable(Of RoomRate)` instance to it

```
' ParseRates() returns IEnumerable(Of RoomRate) '
rates = parse.ParseRates()
```

Looking at your code I assume that you actually need and want only one collection, you should change `rates` variable declaration to:

```
Dim rates As IEnumerable(Of RoomRate)
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. Now it's not returning anything so I need to get to the bottom of that

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with LINQ and reading XML but I believe the error you are getting is caused by the casting of the Select result and IEnumerable(Of RoomRate) because they don't match. Instead you can try .ToList() on the select and have your rates variable of type List(Of RoomRate).

```
Dim rates as List(Of RoomRate) = _xDoc.Descendants("RoomRate").Select(Function(n) New RoomRate With { _
                .GuaranteeSurchargeRequired = n.Attribute("GuarateeSurchargeRequired").Value, _
                .IATACharacteristicIdentification = n.Attribute("IATACharacteristicIdentification").Value, _
                .IATAProductIdentification = n.Attribute("IATAProductIdentification").Value,
                .RPH = n.Attribute("RPH").Value}).ToList()
```